# Dojo: "pathObj is null" error while loading custom dijit

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am getting this error while loading a custom dijit. I have done this mechanically several times before, but I have never got this error.

This is the code:

```
dojo.provide("my.company.widgets.cells.Axon");

(function() {

dojo.require("dijit._Widget");
dojo.require("dijit._Templated");

dojo.require("my.company.widgets.cells.AxonHelper");

var AxonHelper = my.company.widgets.cells.AxonHelper;

dojo.declare("my.company.widgets.cells.Axon", [dijit._Widget, dijit._Templated], {

    postCreate: function() {
        console.debug("Axon#postCreate");
    }


});

})();
```

...and I am calling it this way:

```
dojo.require("my.company.widgets.cells.Axon");
...

var axon = new my.company.widgets.cells.Axon();
```

That's it! error in the console: "**pathObj is null.**"

I am missing something maybe obvious, I just don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `templatePath` or `templateString` property solves the problem :)